# Grails project leveraging Apache Shiro : LegacyShiroFilter uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: grails, shiro

I am working on a grails project that uses Apache Shiro for security.  I am getting this warning when compiling or running the application.

```
Note: /../shiro/grails/LegacyShiroFilter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {

    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"

    compile ":shiro:1.2.1"

}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LegacyShiroFilter` extends `org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter` which is deprecated. If you go to the [plugin's page at grails.org](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) you'll see a link for the plugin source where you can read the class Javadoc (or read it in your plugin install directory) where it says

> Its only reason for existence is to support the legacy `security.shiro.filter.config` setting

which is [described in the release notes](https://grails.org/Shiro+Release+Notes)

> > the security.shiro.filter.config setting is deprecated in favour of security.shiro.filter.filterChainDefinitions + other configuration options. It will continue to work though.